# Spark streaming not reading data from Kinesis

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I have prepared pyspark code to read data from AWS Kinesis in my spark streaming. Code is running fine without any error but not fetching any records.

I have created one kinesis data stream with one shard only and used Kinesis utils for creating kinesis spark stream.

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
ssc = StreamingContext(spark_session.sparkContext, 10)
sc = spark_session.sparkContext
Kinesis_app_name = "test"
Kinesis_stream_name = "aip4_idc_sensor_data"
endpoint_url = "kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
region_name = "us-east-1"

data = KinesisUtils.createStream(
    ssc, Kinesis_app_name, Kinesis_stream_name, endpoint_url,
    region_name, InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 10, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2)


data.pprint()


ssc.start()  # Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()  # Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Command for aws put record:

aws kinesis put-record --stream-name aip4_icd_sensor --data "test" --partition-key "sixty"

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is my kinesis point was stuck far behind latest. Even though it connected to the kinesis, it still trying to read old empty records.
The best way you can do is going to DynamoDB, you will see a table same name as your kinesisAppName. Delete it and try to run again. It works for me. Immediately, I got latest records from the stream